# Redirecting Subdomain to WWW using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain, redirect

I'm trying to redirect a specific subdomain to www.  I already have rules in place that will redirect non-www to www.domain.com.  Here is what I currently have, and it works fine:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.               [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+\.[a-z]{2,6})$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$       http://www.%1/$1      [R=301,L]
```

My problem is that some requests are coming in for **ns2.domain.com**, and I would like those redirected to www.domain.com as well.  Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding an extra `[^.]+\.` in your second condition:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.               [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.([^.]+\.[a-z]{2,6})$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$       http://www.%1/$1      [R=301,L]
```