# Redirect m subdomain to www using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect a site from its old mobile subdomain "m.example.com" to its new responsive domain which is "www.example.com". It needs to redirect subdirectories too, like m.site.com/about/, which should now take users to www.example.com/about/

It is running on Apache2 and Ubuntu.

Here's the .htaccess file and what I thought should work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

I also tried the approach here, but it failed for me too: [Redirecting Subdomain to WWW using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27933536/redirecting-subdomain-to-www-using-htaccess)

Comment: Your rule is fine. Where is this .htaccess file? Is it located on the server containing m.example.com? And is .htaccess enabled using allowoverride directive?

Comment: It's located in /var/www/example.com/m which is the doc root for m.example.com